# finding all the networks the wifi can find

Tags: ios, objective-c

I´m trying to get all the network names my iphone wifi can find and put them in an array. So far I made it only to show the data for the wifi network. I am connected to using :

```
    CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    CFDictionaryRef myWifi = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
    NSLog(@"%@", myWifi);
```

As far as i know from searching so far is that this is all I can get not using external libraries but i cant seems to find any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available to third-Parties (non-Apple devs).  It requires using a private API.

Comment: im not fully sure what is private API but if there is a way to do so can you point for me a direction? im already searching like crazy

Comment: Private means you can't use it.  Obviously, iOS and Apple-provided apps can do this, or the Settings app would not work.  However, your app is not allowed to do it, even if you find the correct API.

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of private library, you can only get the SSID of the network your device is currently connected to.

Comment: what do you mean by a private library? how can i get/create one? how can i truly achieve what im looking for? i just need the right direction

Comment: `Apple80211` or `MobileWiFi.framework` is the framework you are looking for. Look at this [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/743140?tstart=0) and this [thread](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework).